# Unable to download trace file

Tags: android, eclipse, profiling

Whenever I switch to DDMS view and start method profiling, I get the following error message when I stop profiling:

```
Method Profiling Error:

Unable to download trace file:

Remote object doesn't exist!
```

This only happens with 1.6 and 2.1 AVDs, 2.2 and 2.3 work fine. I've been having this problem ever since the latest update to the Eclipse Android plugin. I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 with Android Development Toolkit version 8.0.0.v201011171904-77661. Let me know if you need any more information.

Edit 1:

[Logcat output](http://pastebin.ca/2034034)

Edit 2:

The trace file is actually created on the sdcard and I can pull it with adb or from DDMS file explorer and view it in traceview. I just get the error message when I click on the "stop method profiling" icon and the trace file isn't automatically displayed. I tried deleting the AVDs and creating new ones, installing the latest plugin version, and reinstalling the plugin but the issue remains. I can live with it, but it'd be nice to get it working like it used to.

Answer (score 1):

I've read that this method of profiling works only on Android 2.2 and higher. Sorry, can't find link now.

On lower versions you are still able profile via `Debug.startMethodTracing(); ... Debug.stopMethodTracing();`

**Upd:** check that you have properly mounted sdcard with read/write permissions and check that you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file. May be problem in this, because beginning from Android 2.2 DDMS heap dump requests streaming directly out of the VM, removing the external storage requirement.

If you have all permissions, then post here logcat output please.

P.S. I've found a [document](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/dalvik.git;a=blob_plain;f=docs/heap-profiling.html;hb=HEAD) that I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this is the case because this method of profiling used to work fine up until a week ago on both 1.6 and 2.1, I can't find any references saying they stopped supporting it. I know about setting up profiling in code, but using DDMS is much more convenient.

Comment: I just tried using the permission and made sure the sdcard is properly mounted. Unfortunately, I still get the same error. I found that the trace file is actually created and I can pull it with adb or from DDMS and view it in traceview. It's just not automatically done when I stop profiling. I guess I can live with that, but it'd be cool to get it working again. Added the logcat output to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would check if you can download the file manually with adb pull for starters. At least them you know if there is a problem with the file access and you can also look at it with traceview externally.

In addition you might want to check if there is a bug regarding this feature and/or try the latest release available from aosp since the latest Android tools seem to have issues for a lot of developers.

Of course a clean reinstall or an install of an older version would also help you finding the problem potentially.